# API to query if compute instance was provisioned with legacy Core/RAM combintaion or Flavors

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

For regular cci, I am trying to find from the API any property or flag that tells me that a device was ordered using flavors (package 835 or 1035) vs old RAM/CPU combination (package 46). The information is in the portal so you must have something that tells you but I can't find this info via the API.

If I go to this device that I ordered using flavors (package 1035), under System section, I see "Flavor C1.2x2x100". For older orders where we were ordering using number of cores and RAM (package 46), I do not see it but instead I see RAM and Cores. Upgrade orders for those two types of devices are different so I need to programmatically decide what type of device or package this device belongs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know if your compute instance was provisioned with a flavor or not, try using the following rest api call:

Method: GET

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/[virtualGuestId]/getObject?objectMask=mask[billingItem[id,orderItem[package,preset[package]]]]
```

You will get a response like the below example:

```
{
    "accountId": 11111,
    "createDate": "2018-11-23T04:58:48+08:00",
    "domain": "test.softlayer.com",
    "hostname": "test",
    "id": 22222,
    "maxCpu": 2,
    "maxMemory": 4096,
    "billingItem": {
        "id": 4011111,
        "orderItem": {
            "categoryCode": "guest_core",
            "description": "2 x 2.0 GHz or higher Cores",
            "id": 45222222,
            "order": {
                "accountId": 11111,
                "id": 3233333,            
                "status": "COMPLETED",            
            },
            "preset": {
                "description": "B1.2x4x25",
                "id": 219,                
                "keyName": "B1_2X4X25",
                "name": "B1.2x4x25",
                "packageId": 835,
                "package": {
                    "description": "Public Virtual Server",
                    "firstOrderStepId": 1,
                    "id": 835,
                    "isActive": 1,
                    "keyName": "PUBLIC_CLOUD_SERVER",
                    "name": "Public Virtual Server",
                    "subDescription": "Public Virtual Server",
                    "unitSize": 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great. billingItem[orderItem] is what I was looking for.